# BadPaddingException with Cipher class

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I'm coding a program that generates a simmetrical AES key, encodes it using an assimetrical public key, writes that encoded AES key in a plain text file, and then it recovers the encoded AES key and decodes it.

This is the function that encodes the AES key and returns it as byte[]:

```
private static byte[] EncodeKey(String valueToEncode, Key myKey)
{
    byte[] encodedKey = null;

    try
    {
        //Cipher
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "SunJCE");

        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey);

        //Encoding
        encodedKey = c.doFinal(valueToEncode.getBytes());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    } //try

    return encodedKey;
} //CifrarCadenaRSA
```

Then I write this byte array in a txt file with this another function:

```
private static void WriteTextFile(String path, byte[] valueToWrite)
{
    try
    {
        //Check if file exists
        File f = new File(path);

        if (f.exists())
        {
            f.delete();
        } //if

        f.createNewFile();

        //FileOutputStream
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

        //Writing
        fos.write(valueToWrite);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    } //try
} //EscribirArchivoTexto
```

And finally, I load the encoded data and try to decode it:

```
private static Key DecodeKeyFromFile(String path, Key keyToDecode)
{
    //Clave descifrada
    Key decodedKey = null;

    try
    {
        //File
        File f = new File(ruta);

        //Reading text file
        byte[] encodedKey = Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());

        //Cipher for decoding
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "SunJCE");

        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, clave);

        //Decoding: THIS IS THROWING BadPaddingException
        byte[] keyBytes = c.doFinal(encodedKey);

        decodedKey = (Key) new SecretKeySpec(claveBytes, 0, claveBytes.length, "AES");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    } //try

    return decodedKey;
} //CargarClaveCifrada
```

As you can see, I use the same algorithm and padding for both encoding and decoding. I also tried using "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" but nothing changes. So why is decoding throwing a BadPaddingException?

The exception I get:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
```

And the trace:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
at cifradoHibrido.CifradoHibrido.DecodeKeyFromFile(CifradoHibrido.java:197)
at cifradoHibrido.CifradoHibrido.DecodeMessage(CifradoHibrido.java:174)
at cifradoHibrido.CifradoHibrido.main(CifradoHibrido.java:98)
```

Comment: In the `DecodeKeyFromFile`-method the ciphertext is stored in a Utf8-string. Since a ciphertext consists of arbitrary byte-sequences, the data are corrupted. However, the conversion isn't necessary at all, because `Cipher#doFinal` expects a byte-array. The ciphertext must simply be read with `byte[] encodedKey = Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());` and decrypted with `byte[] keyBytes = c.doFinal(encodedKey);`.

Comment: I tried that as edited in the question. Still getting BadPaddingException on Cipher.doFinal

Comment: can you paste exception

Comment: Pasted on question alongside with exception trace

Comment: Your code runs on my machine without any problems. I copied it to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/iUD5E1Ad. You should also replace the variables `ruta`, `clave` and `claveBytes` (`path`, `keyToDecode`, `keyBytes`) in the _posted_ `DecodeKeyFromFile`-method. Maybe something is wrong here. There is also a resource leak (but code ran on my machine without this fix). Maybe there is something wrong with your keys. Check if the pastebin-code is running on your machine.

Comment: Sorry for being idle a little. Your code did work, so I guess there's something wrong with how I recover the keys I use from a KeyStore or the padding methods I'm using.

Comment: Update: I fixed this error using CBC instead of ECB on simmetric coding and decoding. I'm now getting another error nonetheless: final block not properly padded. Also I printed the keys before storing them in the KeyStore and after recovering them from the KeyStore and that's working fine. So this is probably an issue with the padding method I'm using.

Comment: Another update: I made a smaller program that makes all the process of hybrid encription on memory, without storing anything on files, and it's perfectly working. So there must be some data corruption when storing or recovering data from files in the main program.

Comment: The code above uses many bad constructions, hiding exceptions, returning `null` on errors, using `String.getBytes()`  without specifying the character encoding, explicitly providing a provider name, not streaming or mapping files, not keeping to Java naming conventions etc. etc. I'm not surprised that things go wrong if this mirrors the code quality at your organization.